# React JS MUI DataGrid no rows or data

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I have a MUI's Data Grid component, and I'm fetching data using axios promise, of course the purpose is to show the data fetched to the Data Grid component, when I consoled the rows array before and after the datagrid component render to dom.
Here is the grid component:

```
const Grid= (props) => {
const rowsData = props.stats
const columns= props.columns
  return (
    <TableContainer>
    <DataGrid
      columns={columns}
      rows={rowsData}
      autoHeight
      rowsPerPageOptions={[100]}
      checkboxSelection={false}
    />
  </TableContainer>
  );
}
export default StatsGrid
```

The fetching function:

```
import axios from 'axios';
const SRVADDRESS = 'http://localhost:31096/api'

export const getAllStats = async (object) =>{
    let stats = []
    const {clientName, clientId, isMobile, token } = object
    let eventToReq = {
        'clientName':clientName,
        'clientId':clientId,
        'isMobile':isMobile
    }
    let config = {
        headers:{
            Authorization:'Bearer ' + token
            }
    }
    
    try{
        await axios.post(`${SRVADDRESS}/getAllStats`,eventToReq, config)
        .then((res)=>{
            stats=res.data[0]
            console.log(stats)
            return stats
        })
```

the Main Component when I call the fetch data function and render the Grid component :

```
const Main = () => {
    const user = useContext(AuthContext)
    console.log(user)
    let object = {
        clientName:user.auth.clientName,
        clientId:user.auth.clientId,
        isMobile:mobile(),
        token:user.auth.token
    }
    let stats=[]
    useEffect(()=>{
        try{
        getAllStats(object)
        .then((response)=>{
            console.log(response)
            let clientName= response.clientName
            let stats= response.stats
            console.log(stats)
            return stats
        })
    } catch{err=>console.log(err)}
    },[user])
    
  return (
      <div>
          <Container>
            <Grid stats={stats} columns={columns}/>
        </Container>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Main
```

Comment: Add more information like the fetching functions to have more context

Comment: I added the main component and the fetching function